# How to select a table from highest table use LinQ query

Tags: linq

I have a sequence relationship:

A has many Bs.
B has many Cs.
C has many Ds.

They also make me so confused if there are more than 3 or 4,..tables.

So, how can i select all Cs that satify A.Id="1".
(something likes finding all grandsons of a grandfather)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Linq-to-sql since you mention "table" in the topic.

```
var query = from c in context.C
            where c.b.a.id == "1"
            select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from a in aArray
        from b in a.bArray
        from c in b.cArray
        where a.id == "1"
        select c;
```